# Do Loop within PROC PHREG

Tags: sas, survival-analysis

Can someone tell me if these two would be equivalent?

```
PROC PHREG DATA=data;
ARRAY start{*} exp_start1-exp_start100;
ARRAY stop{*} exp_STOP1-exp_STOP100;
use=0;
DO I=1 TO 100;
IF stop{I}>start{I} AND start{I}<time2event THEN use=1;
END;
MODEL time2event*censor(1)=use/risklimits covb;
RUN;
```

AND:

```
data _want;
data _have;
ARRAY start{*} exp_start1-exp_start100;
ARRAY stop{*} exp_STOP1-exp_STOP100;
use=0;
DO I=1 TO 100;
IF stop{I}>start{I} AND start{I}<time2event THEN use=1;
END;
run;
**PROC PHREG DATA=_want;**
MODEL time2event*censor(1)=use/risklimits covb;
RUN;
```

Basically, can do the DO loop be outside of the PROC PHREG procedure when trying to incorporate time-dependent covariates?

Thanks!

Comment: No, they are not the same. You can run them and see that you'll obtain different results.